# Rails AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I have form's field and want to use with `select2`

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_ids, Product.all,:id, :name ,{},{ class: 'p_ids', multiple: true} %>
```

my js

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".p_ids").select2({
        tags:true,
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
    });
});
```

my params

```
params.require(:cost).permit(:day, :amount, :description, :source, product_ids:[])
```

but i have got

`Product(#70204276011560) expected, got NilClass(#70204185305100)`

log

```
"cost"=>{"day"=>"15-10-2016", "amount"=>"100", "description"=>"test", "source"=>"products", "product_ids"=>["", "1", "2"]}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this error occures by empty value at the head of product_ids array in the log.

```
"product_ids"=>["", "1", "2"]
```

And you can remove empty value by include_hidden: false option like below.

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_ids, Product.all, :id, :name, { include_hidden: false }, { class: 'p_ids', multiple: true } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select :product_ids, Product.all.order(:name).collect{|c| [ c.name, c.id] }, {include_blank: false }, id: 'p_ids_selection', multiple: true, class: 'multiple' %>
```

js section is that

```
    $(function() {
     $("#p_ids_selection").select2({
      placeholder: "Select Product"
     });
   });
```